# How to add v-tooltip for v-combobox? issues

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have added code for v-tooltip but it doesn't display when I hover the combobox , do you see mistakes or in the order of the code, let me know, please.Thanks .

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <v-tooltip top>
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
        <v-combobox
          bottom
          chips
          :items="items"
          label="Choose videos"
          multiple
        />
      </template>
      <span>Left tooltip aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span>
    </v-tooltip>
  </div>
</template>
```

[When I hover the combobox , nothing happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z23fN.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not applying the activator slot attributes.

Secondly, the combo box creates a parent element that wraps the input that the activator attributes bind to.

This breaks the tooltip, causing it to only trigger when the box input is clicked on.

What you need to do is also wrap your combo box in a div and apply the activator to the div like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-tooltip top>
      <template #activator="{on, attrs}">
        <div multiple v-on="on">
          <v-combobox
            bottom
            chips
            :items="items"
            label="Choose videos"
            v-bind="attrs"
          />
        </div>
      </template>
      <span>Left tooltip aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span>
    </v-tooltip>
  </div>
</template>
```

This same fix also applies to other Vuetify elements such as `v-select` which also create their own parent elements.

Comment: The tooltip appears but when I click the combobox and hover for that moment.  Is there anything else for adding to appear the tooltip before clicking ? , thanks

Comment: I'll test it myself in a moment. Perhaps the combobox itself creates a different parent element and it's binding to some sort of child element that's only active when the combo is clicked on? I'm just guessing but I can investigate later this evening and take a look if you still have the issue

Comment: Yup just confirmed @GabrielQuezadaCastro The v-bind and v-on get attached to the input itself. The input is then wrapped in the parent element

Comment: Fixed it @GabrielQuezadaCastro check my updated answer

Comment: Hello @Jordan , I would like to ask you , why do you add a #activator="{on,attrs}" , I guess the value of on is when I hover the combobox, what about attrs ? or how does it work ? . I put this  v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }"> and this is a bit different . Can you explain me , thanks

Comment: @GabrielQuezadaCastro It's the shorthand form of v-slot. So # is just a short way of wriging v-slow. Similar to how : is shorthand for v-bind and @ is shorthand for v-on, Make sure to upvote my answer if you found it helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
<div>
   <v-combobox
      bottom
      chips
      :items="items"
      label="Choose videos"
      multiple
   />
   <v-tooltip activator="parent" location="top">Font</v-tooltip>
</div>
```